# C# winform Menustrip merging problem

Tags: c#, winforms, menu

```
class MDIFormMenu: System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip
{

}

class ChildFormMenu: System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip
{

}
```

I used MDIFormMenu on MDIForm set  MainMenuStrip property and ChildFormMenu added on ChildForm. It is failed to merge.

If I used same class menu on both form it works.

Please help me, what am  I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "merging"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ChildFormMenu must be derived from MDIFormMenu. This behavior is perhaps by design.

```
class ChildFormMenu: MDIFormMenu
{

}
```